# (TypeError) dot operation in numpy and theano

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, theano

I write a following code:

```
import theano
import numpy

p=theano.tensor.dmatrix('p')
q=theano.tensor.dmatrix('q')
r=theano.tensor.dot(p,q)

f=theano.function([p,q], r)

a=numpy.array([1,2])
b=numpy.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
```

Then `numpy.dot(a,b)` returns `array([ 9, 12, 15])`. I think `f(a,b)` returns the same thing but it fails(TypeError). The error message says

> Wrong number of dimensions: expected 2, got 1 with shape (2,).

What's happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change line 4 to `p=theano.tensor.dvector('p')`. Theano is more strict on typing than numpy.

Comment: How do you write if you want to use a $n\times m$ matrix but $n$ is equal to 1 under a condition? Should I write two function and use them based on the condition of $n〉1$?